# Default custom options

Tags: r, knitr

I would like to create a default chunk option for my documents, so that I can choose which chunks are included in the appendix. Here is my MWE:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE, appendix=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(appendix=TRUE)
```

```{r}
# some code included in the appendix
```

```{r appendix=FALSE}
# some code not included in the appendix
```

# Appendix
```{r, ref.label=knitr::all_labels(appendix), echo = T, eval = F}
```
````

I would like to include all the chunks that do not explicitly say `appendix=TRUE`. If I add that, it works as expected, but the default `knitr::opts_chunk$set(appendix=TRUE)` does not seem to work.

I am probably missing something in my setup. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is I believe possible to do what you propose. See Rmarkdown example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set:

- `Appendix <- TRUE` in  `setOptions`

you then set -

- `knitr::opts_chunk$set(appendix = TRUE)`

now any chunk without `Appendix = FALSE` is included in the Appendix.

**Note:** It is important to include `Appendix = FALSE` in the Appendix chunk.

I hope the above helps, it is how I do this.

````
---
title: "47085866-2"
author: "Technophobe1"
date: "11/5/2017"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
---

```{r setOptions, echo = FALSE, Appendix = FALSE}
Appendix <- TRUE
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, error = FALSE, warning = FALSE, results = 'hide')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(appendix = TRUE)

```

## Appendix = TRUE

```{r code}
# some code included in the appendix

setClass(
  "CStruct",
  slots = list(
    powerLevel = "numeric",
    size = "numeric"
  )
)

CStructure <- new("CStruct", powerLevel = 5, size = 10)
CStructure
str(CStructure)
CStructure@powerLevel
CStructure@size

```

## Appendix = FALSE
```{r ref.label='code', Appendix = FALSE}
# some code not included in the appendix
setClass(
  "CStruct2",
  slots = list(
   n = "numeric",
   s = "character",
   b = "logical"
  )
)

CStructure2 <- new("CStruct2", n = c(2, 3, 5), 
                  s = c("aa", "bb"), 
                  b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) )
str(CStructure2)
CStructure2@n
CStructure2@s
CStructure2@b
```
# Code Appendix
```{r, ref.label=knitr::all_labels(Appendix), Appendix = FALSE, echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
## Code Appendix


```
````

### Output:

[image]

Comment: I spent ages trying to crack this property. Happy to know it is possible

Comment: No worries - happy to help.

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes my life a lot easier.

Comment: @CaiusBrindescu - Great glad I could help. Take care.